# AngularJS Logging Out and Logging back in

Tags: javascript, angularjs, django, cookies

I have an index file that has some directives-

```
<div ng-if="$hide">
        <ba-sidebar></ba-sidebar>
        <page-top></page-top>

        <div class="al-main">
            <div class="al-content">
            <content-top></content-top>
            <div ui-view></div>
            </div>
       </div>
    </div>
  <div ng-if="!$hide">
      <login-view></login-view>
  </div>
```

What this does is it shows the content if a user successfully logs in. The code for logging in is-

```
$interval(function(){
    var token = $cookies.get('token');
    if(token === undefined){
        $rootScope.$hide = false;
    }
    else{
        $rootScope.$hide = true;
    }
}, 300)
```

The interval function keeps a check on cookies for token that is send from the backend(django) and switches the views. If there is a token, it shows the main content, if not, it loads up the log-in directive.

To log out, what I do is delete these cookies and set them to null, which automatically changes the view back to log-in directive.

Once logged out, page switches to log-in.

**The problem**-

When I try to log-in with a different user, at the backend, the user gets switched but as soon as the view changes to the main content, it loads up the data from the previous user until whole page is refreshed(manually).

- I do not seem to understand why as ng-if recreates the whole DOM, shouldn't it load up the new data?
- If not, how to load up the new data?

Answer (score 1):

The problem is not with `ng-if` as far as I can see. When you clear your token, you should also clear the user object that you use to populate your DOM. Right now there're two dependencies - the cookie and the user object.

When you remove the token, make sure you clear the user object. If the `ng-if` is dependent only on your token, that means that during the gap between your login and your user object's population, the old user object will still be valid and the `$hide` would be false, thereby showing your old user data

Comment: I'm sorry but which user object are you talking about? When I remove the token, I empty the credential variables.

Comment: Let me ask you this-how do you show the user data on the screen?